# Volume slider is playing audio files correctly onClick but not changing the volume of key presses for the same element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Basically if I change the slider level it only affects the click and not also the keydown, even though they call the same playSound Function. Not sure what I have messed up

```
function App() {
  const [soundText, setSoundText] = useState();
  const [volumeLevel, setVolumeLevel] = useState(0.5)
};
```

I have it split by component, I had to cut out most of the App component to post, but you get the point

```
function DrumPad({ pad, setSoundText, volumeLevel }) {
    
    useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyPress);
        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyPress)
        };
    }, []);

    const playSound = () => {
        const audioTag = document.getElementById(pad.letter);
        audioTag.volume = volumeLevel;
        audioTag.play();
        setSoundText(pad.id)
    }
    const handleKeyPress = (e) => {
        if(e.keyCode === pad.keyCode){
            playSound();
        }
    }
    

    return (
        <div 
        className="drum-pad" 
        id={pad.id}
        onClick={playSound}>
            <p>{pad.letter}</p>
            <audio 
                src={pad.src} 
                className="clip" 
                id={pad.letter}>
            </audio>
        </div>
    )
}
```

```
function VolumeBar({ setSoundText, volumeLevel, setVolumeLevel }) {
    const volumeChanger = (e) => {
        setVolumeLevel(e.target.value)
    }
    return (
        <div className="slide-container">
            Volume
            <input 
                id="myRange"
                type="range"
                min='0'
                max='1'
                step= '0.01'
                value={ volumeLevel }
                onChange={ volumeChanger }
                className="slider"
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

.useEffect should depend on a **pad**. So it runs useEffect everytime pad changes (either keypress or onClick event)
This should work:

```js
function DrumPad({ pad, setSoundText, volumeLevel }) {
    
    useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyPress);
        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyPress)
        };
    }, [pad]); // add *pad* here instead of having empty []
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using event listener, which are not encouraged in react, try to add *onKeyDown* props to the input.

```
  <input 
            id="myRange"
            type="range"
            min='0'
            max='1'
            step= '0.01'
            value={ volumeLevel }
            onChange={ volumeChanger }
            onKeyDown={(e) => {
               if(e.keyCode === pad.keyCode){
                 playSound();
               }}}
            className="slider"
        />
```

Comment: 'pad' is scoped to DrumPad. how do i pass pad over. in the App return, I mapped over an array of objects and each returned a 'pad' to DrumPad

Comment: If you cant pass it as a props, just move the scope one level higher, so you can then pass it to all the components that needs it.

Comment: If im understing right, you want to trigger the playSound both when user clicks the div or when the users clicks the right pad key right? If that's the case i will update the code.

Comment: my code already does that, it triggers playSound with a click or a keypress. playSound references volumeLevel in state. But when I change the volume slider, only the volume of clicks is changed. keypresses are always the same volume. even though they both call playSound